# search and extracting values from text using python

Tags: python

Given the following `Jtree memory segment`:

```
print (resptext)

SENT: Ukern command: show jtree 0 memory
Jtree memory segment 0 (Context: 0x45bdc9c8)

-------------------------------------------
Memory Statistics:
   16777216 bytes total
    7591528 bytes used
    9181968 bytes available (9155584 bytes from free pages)
       3528 bytes wasted
        192 bytes unusable
      32768 pages total
      14751 pages used (2571 pages used in page alloc)
        135 pages partially used
      17882 pages free (max contiguous = 17846)

Jtree memory segment 1 (Context: 0x45c5ed20)
Memory Statistics:
   16777216 bytes total
   13462008 bytes used
    3304560 bytes available (3281408 bytes from free pages)
       2432 bytes wasted
       8216 bytes unusable
      32768 pages total
      26220 pages used (8970 pages used in page alloc)
        139 pages partially used
       6409 pages free (max contiguous = 6409)


Context: 0x43bd2958
```

#### Goals:

1. extract `bytes total` and `bytes used` from each segment
2. calculate the percentage memory usage for segment 0 and segment 1:

   - segment_0 = bytes used/bytes available = 45.45%
   - segment_1 = bytes used/bytes available = 80.24%

```
resptext = resptext.strip().split('\n')
resptext = [s.strip() for s in resptext]
for line in resptext:
    line = line.strip()
    if 'bytes used' in line:
        words = line.partition(" bytes")
        bytes_used = words[0]
        print (bytes_used)
```

#### Current state:

- I've managed to extract and print the values, but I couldn't do the calculation operation for segment_0 memory utilization and segment_1
- output so far:

```
7591528
13462008
```

Comment: Clarified the goals of the question

Answer (score 0):

Can probably keep this simple. Filter the lines for the values you care about and then zip the contents together:

```
segment_lines = (line for line in resptext if "Jtree memory segment" in line)
used_lines = (line for line in resptext if "bytes used" in line)
avail_lines = (line for line in resptext if "bytes available" in line)

segment_values = (int(line.split(" ")[3]) for line in segment_lines)
used_values = (int(line.split(" ")[0]) for line in used_lines)
avail_values = (int(line.split(" ")[0]) for line in avail_lines)

segment_values = {
    segment: {"used": used, "available": avail}
    for segment, used, avail in zip(
        segment_values, used_values, avail_values
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use regular expressions? It's more straightforward ! and you can test your regex [here](https://regex101.com/). I have worked with log data and regular expressions were a lot of help.